# How do I use the error prop and css for Input API of Material UI with context

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need to use the MUI Input API props and CSS for `{error}` and its use.

My code looks like this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(cell.value);
const [startAdornment, setStartAdornment] = useState<adornmentTypes>("");
const [endAdornment, setEndAdornment] = useState<adornmentTypes>("");
const [error, seterror] = useState<error>(false);

<Input
  id={id}
  value={value}
  onChange={_onChange} //have a method
  onBlur={_onBlur} //have a method
  onFocus={_handleFocus} //have a method
  startAdornment={startAdornment} //have switch cases on special character $,% etc
  endAdornment={endAdornment}
  error={error} />
```

Now as per material docs `error - bool - If true, the input will indicate an error. This is normally obtained via context from FormControl.`

And for pseudo class `error - .Mui-error - Pseudo-class applied to the root element if error={true}.`

Now I can't get around to use the error state to true because of value type described as a string!

What am I missing? Please help!

Comment: Hi @keikai apologies for not responding back in time - yes that helped big time - the problem is that i am trying to use cass/cscc not the styled components type - and it took sometime but figured it out looking at the documentation u suggested. Thanks! I cannot upvote the answer as a newbie though :)

Answer (score 0):

We can see from the Material-UI document of [Input API](https://material-ui.com/api/input/)

For props: **error**

> Type: `bool`
>   Description: If true, the input will indicate an error.

For css: **error**

> Global class: `.Mui-error`
>   Description: Pseudo-class applied to the root element if error={true}.

They are two different things, we can use them like below:

```
<Input
  ...
  error={errorFlag}
  classes={{error: classes.errorStyleClass}}
/>
```

If the props error's value is true, the CSS error's styles would be applied.

---

That's the concept of those kinds of stuff. Since there is no more info we can get from the post, if there are further problems, kindly make an update.